# Excel: Text mining using IF, ISNUMBER, SEARCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to clean up job title data using the formula below:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"admin","reception","account","finance","HR","public","sales","customer","creative","IT","human"},A1))),"",A1)
```

It should work by eliminating job titles with any of the texts specified in the quotes above. However, I've encountered an issue where it doesn't. In a case where the job title is Quantity Surveyor, the title contains none of the specified texts but Excel seems to reflect it as such. What am I not doing right here?

[Quantity Surveyor Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux4QK.png)

Comment: it's because of quant`IT`y

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select the part of formula of `search`, and then press `F9`. You will find the match result of 6, where it has original value of 'IT', it means Quant**it**y, has `IT`.

[image]
[image]

---

I really donot know why there is negative vote as not useful.

---

Here is the formula to solve your problem

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/FIND({"admin","reception","account","finance","HR","public","sales","customer","creative","IT","human"},A1)),A1)
```

[image]

Of course, it is better to define a range instead of hard code {}, like below

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/FIND($J$2:$J$7,A2),$K$2:$K$7),A2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have missed that!

Comment: You can check my edit content, here I show you a better formula. @Esther

Comment: Hi Anabas, the lookup formula works great. Thank you so much for showing me a better solution to the issue! To be clear, I did not downvote your comment and I've tried to upvote it multiple times but I currently don't have enough reputation for it to show. My apologies and thank you!

Comment: It is okay. Enjoy it :)

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the information you are looking for, this is the formula you want to use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"admin","reception","account","finance","HR","public","sales","customer","creative","human"},A1)),NOT(SEARCH("Quantity",A1))),"",A1),"")
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The formula worked after eliminating the 'IT' text string in the quotes. However, is there any way I can eliminate job titles with a case-sensitive 'IT' in the title, while making sure that the 'it' in Quantity isn't picked up?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The `NOT` portion of my answer can be pieced together the same way as the first `SEARCH` to add additional clauses to your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So essentially with the NOT function, I'll have to specify all the job titles that I'm interested to look for, apart from Quantity Surveyor? It could be a bit more tedious as I have more than 100 titles that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Using countif you don't need to check for errors if they occur:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A1,{"admin","reception","account","finance","HR","public","sales","customer","creative","human"}))+COUNTIF(A1,"<>Quantity"),"",A1)
```